# wpf datagrid - how to remove black selected border?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need help, 
when I click at datagrid at cell, I want to select all line like in image ([please look at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuXcp.jpg)), but without black border. how to disable, or change color to transparent? I tried this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

but don't work. nothing changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to style the `selected cell` not just cells. To do so you need to write this inside your `style` tag:

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

All you need was using `Triggers` hope it will work for you. Also you can change background for selected cell or whatever property you want.

Comment: great! also can you tell my how to change color this border? BorderColor not exist

Comment: I have ;)                                 <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Following example to  customize wpf datagrid (border, cell corners, etc.). You can modify it as you wish.

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Page.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Border Background="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                  <Border x:Name="border"
                          BorderBrush="White"
                          BorderThickness="2"
                          Background="Black"
                          CornerRadius="5">
                      <ContentPresenter />
                  </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="rowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
  </Style>

 <Grid>  
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" IsReadOnly="true"
  RowStyle="{StaticResource rowStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}" 
  Background="Black" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" />
 </Grid>
 </Page>
```